# Does the number of actions a group can have on the left cosets of a subgroup of index $n$ tell us anything about the number of such subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I have a question asking me to show that the number of index $n$ subgroups of a group $G$ of rank $r$ is bounded above, and it offers the hint that I should consider the number of actions $G$ can have on a specific index $n$ subgroup $H$'s left cosets.

However, I am struggling to see why this is helpful for this question, since I can't quite understand how this relates to other index $n$ subgroups.

I suspect that it will involve some sort of pigeonhole argument, but I can't immediately how.

I think regarding the number of actions that $G$ can have on the left cosets of $H$, we can consider the action of a generating set of size $r$. Specifically as we want just an upper bound (I think), we may ignore whether or not the action of the generating set actually extends appropriately to group action of $G$. Specifically, we can just pick arbitrary mappings of each left coset, for each of the $r$ generators.

In that case for fixed generator $g_1$, it can send any of the $n$ left cosets to any others, giving a total upper bound of $n^n$ mappings. Considering then that there are $r$ generators, that we may regard as "independent", we see there are at most $n^{nr}$ total actions it can have on $G/H$. This is then an upper bound for the total number of group actions $G$ may have on the set of left cosets $G/H$.

I suppose now we consider another group of index $n$, and consider how each of it's left cosets intersect with the left cosets of $H$? I'm not really sure what I can learn about them though, since it is an arbitrary group of index $n$.

[EDIT]: As noted in the comments, the upper bound for the number of actions may be improved to $n!^r$.

Comment: The maps have to be bijections, so you can make that $n!^r$, and that'a a bound on the number of subgroups, because the action determines the subgroup as the stabilizer of the first point.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for the improvement. Are you saying that we fix some $x \in G/H$ and consider it's stabiliser under every single action that $G$ can have on $G/H$? Or are you saying we look at stabilisers of all left-cosets, for all actions $G$ can have? Either, I assume then it is known that every subgroup of index $n$ arises such a stabiliser, but I can't quite see why that might be obvious?

Comment: We can label the cosets of of any index $n$ subgroup as $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and assume that the coset $H$ is always numbered $1$. Any subgroup $H$ of index $n$ determines such an action in which the stabilizer of $H$ is $1$ (in fact it determines many such actions, because you can number the other cosets any way you like) , so the total number of actions is a (crude) upper bound on the total number of  subgroups of index $n$.

Comment: I am sorry I am still quite confused. Specifically: Is the second occurence of $H$ in your comment the same as the first? Also, what do you mean "in which the stabiliser of $H$ is $1$"? Isn't $1$ a coset here? And more importantly isn't $1$ equal to $H$ here?

Comment: Sorry I meant the stabilizer of $1$ is $H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt okay thank you. Are you saying that if we fix a subgroup $H$, then all other subgroups $B$ of the same index arise as the stabiliser of $1$ in $G/H$ for some action of $G$ on $G/H$? Basically, in your earlier comment, is the second occurence of $H$ the same $H$ as the first?

Comment: Every subgroup of index $n$ in $G$ arises as the stabilizer of $1$ in some action of $G$ on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. So the total number of such actions is an upper bound on the total number of subgroups of index $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should perhaps make my comments into an answer.

An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is determined by the action of its generators, so if $G$ is generated by $r$ elements then the number of actions is at most $n!^r$, where $|X|=n$.

Now, for any subgroup $H$ of $G$ of index $n$, there is an action of $G$ on the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$, where $g \in G$ maps coset $xH$ to $gxH$. We can number the cosets $1,2,\ldots,n$, where $H$ is numbered $1$, giving us an action of $G$ on $X = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Then, in this action,  $H$ is the stabilizer of $1 \in X$, so different subgroups define different actions.

So for every subgroup $H$ of index $n$ in $G$, there is an action of $G$ on $X$ in which $H$ is the stabilizer of $1$. So the total number of such subgroups is bounded above by the total number of actions, which is $n!^r$.

In fact every subgroup of index $n$ gives rise to many different actions in this way, because we can choose the numbering of the cosets other than $H$ any way we like. Also, not every choice of $r$ permutation sof $X$ gives rise to an action of $G$ on $X$, and only the transitive actions arise as coset actions. So this upper bound is usually very imprecise.